# No me deja autenticar con facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-api, oauth

Realice toda la configuración siguiendo un vídeo tutorial, como url del sitio explican que debe de ser: http://localhost:3000.

Sin embargo al tratar de autenticarme me genera el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿has probado [alguna de estas soluciones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37200021/895789)? quizás el tutorial es viejo y no considera nuevas restricciones de seguridad implementadas por facebook.

Comment: Aquí hay [otra explicación](https://wp-native-articles.com/blog/news/how-to-fix-facebook-apps-error-cant-load-url-domain-url-isnt-included-apps-domains/) más detallada.

Comment: Ya me dejo avanzar, si, el vídeo tutorial es con la versión de RoR 4 y el error era generado porque en el vídeo no configuran este parámetro URI de redirección de OAuth válidos con http://localhost:3000, corregí ese problema y ahora me genera error con el método facebook: The action 'facebook' could not be found for Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

Answer (score 0):

Creo haber tenido alguna vez ese problema y es porque Facebook no tiene forma de acceder a tu entorno local, así que tienes que disponer de una url pública para que pueda acceder a los callbacks.
Una opción sencilla es instalar [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) y luego bindeas el puerto de rails a una dirección pública ejecutando:

```
ngrok http 3000
```

Luego la dirección que te muestre en consola (que va a ser del tipo `http://2d265ad4.ngrok.io`) la agregas a tu configuración de facebook.

Comment: lo extraño es que en el vídeo el configura la dirección solo como http://localhost:3000 y le funciona. No muestra ni explica de que haya que bindear el puerto, pero voy a aprobar su solución y le digo como me fue.

Comment: hice el procedimiento y sigue generando el mismo error. Corrí el comando ./ngrok http 3000 y agregue a la configuración la dirección que me generó  http://1ca2716f.ngrok.io Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.